# How can I make a port 35810 to work in https in a Azure VM?

Tags: azure, port, azure-virtual-machine

I need to access the port 35810 on https. When I try http://xxxx:35810 its work, but not https://xxx:35810.

I have already opened the port 35810 (Inbound rule), but don't know how to open in https.

Is a VM fron AZURE

Comment: Have you installed SSL certificate on the server and bind it to port 35810 in IIS? See this link for more details: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO14335.html

Comment: What kind of a web server are you using? IIS, apache, nginx?

Comment: I am using IIS windows

Comment: Also its not a ordanary website, its from a service... so I cant see it in IIS sites

Comment: I think you need to enable the SSL for the https. Try to follow the steps in [Secure a web server on Azure VM with SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server).

Comment: Could you look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl) if it helps?